# partitioned drive will not accept files

Tags: permissions, partitioning, ownership

I have two partitions on my 2Tb drive. The Linux partition will not allow me to save anything there, but it is working correctly.
Earlier I tried to set it up as a boot partition. Now it says the owner is root.
I resized the partition correctly,but I need to change ownership of the partition to use it for files ?

Comment: I am currently using 14.04 LTS but I am planning to update to 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

> but I need to change ownership of the partition to use it for files ?

Yes.

The command for that is `chown`.

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /dir_of_disk/
```

- the -R makes it recursive.
- $USER will use the loginname of the user you have active at that time.
- this will make the disk read/write for that user.